# CakePHP 3.6: Setup database session to logout user after 8 hours of inactivity

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I am trying to setup a database session in CakePHP 3.6 in order to log out users after 8 hours of inactivity. I created the table and set in `app.php`:

```
'Session' => [
        'defaults' => 'database',
        'timeout'  => 480,  // 8 hours, refers to 'session.gc_maxlifetime' in PHP settings
        'cookieTimeout' => 10 * 480, // 80 hours, refers to 'session.cookie_lifetime' in PHP settings 
    ]
```

But in the database, after I log in I can see that `expires` value of my session is: `1559992416` which is 10 days after the last time of activity (`modified` value). But even if I set `expires` in 2 minutes after the current time, it doesn't log me out when I try to click a button in my application. How I can set it up correctly?

Comment: Please check the below answer

Comment: Make sure that `ini_set()` works and [**the session object modifies `session.gc_maxlifetime` as expected**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.7.7/src/Http/Session.php#L208-L210), and that your system time is set correctly (`expires` is `time() + session.gc_maxlifetime`). Also there is no `cookieTimeout` option anymore in CakePHP 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `cookie_lifetime`

```
Configure::write('Session', [
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'ini' => [
        'session.cookie_lifetime' => 1800, // Valid for 30 minutes
    ]
]);
```

For more explanation you can check below link

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html#setting-ini-directives

Comment: I tried that already but with no luck... thats why I ended up using database for storing the session

Comment: no don't do that.that is not the standard way to do.i will come up with a solution